# Accessing primitive types in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, objectmapper, realm

I am using ObjectMapper along with RealmSwift and my class looks like:

```
class Location: Object, Mappable {
    var Lat : Float = 0
    var Lng : Float = 0

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        Lat <- map["Lat"];
        Lng <- map["Lng"];
    }
}
```

This Location class is referenced in another class Vehicle.swift which is also a subclass of Realm Object

I am able to access the location of the vehicle using the line:

```
let location : Location = vehicle.VehicleLocation!
```

Printing the value of location gives me the output:

```
location is  Location {
    Lat = 49.24122;
    Lng = -123.1153;
}
```

I opened the realm database using the Realm browser and the values correspond with those in the database.

However when I try to to access the `Lat` and `Lng` values, I am getting `0.0`. I am trying to access these using :

```
let lat : Float = vehicle.VehicleLocation!.Lat
let lng : Float = vehicle.VehicleLocation!.Lng
```

Any idea what might be happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All stored Realm properties must be defined as `dynamic`.

Change:

```
var Lat : Float = 0
var Lng : Float = 0
```

To:

```
dynamic var Lat : Float = 0
dynamic var Lng : Float = 0
```